# Custom Labels over the bar graph (CorePlot Framework)

Tags: ios4, label, core-plot

i have used CorePlot for the first time and want now customize the Bar Graph. You see it in this picture.

[image]

I want now add the Number over every Bar on top of the Bar

hope you know what i mean.

How can i realize it?

This is my Code

```
-(void) generateDataSamples
{
    int rawSamples [] = {1,3,6,2,1,1,3,15,2,1};
    int numSamples = sizeof(rawSamples) / sizeof(int);

    samples = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numSamples];

    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++){
        double x = i;
        double y = rawSamples[i];
        NSDictionary *sample = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x],X_VAL,
                                [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y],Y_VAL,
                                nil];
        [samples addObject:sample];
    }   
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self generateDataSamples];

    double xAxisStart = 0;
    double xAxisLength = [samples count];

    double yAxisStart = 0;
    double yAxisLength = [[samples valueForKeyPath:@"@max.Y_VAL"] doubleValue];


    CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];

    CPXYGraph *graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;



    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(0)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength +1)];

    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(0)
                                                   length:CPDecimalFromDouble(yAxisLength + 0.5)];  

    CPBarPlot *plot = [[CPBarPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot.plotRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromDouble(0.0)
                                                 length:CPDecimalFromDouble(xAxisLength)];

    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet; 
    CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle]; 
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor whiteColor]; 
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f; 
    CPTextStyle *cyanStyle = [CPTextStyle textStyle]; 
    cyanStyle.color = [CPColor cyanColor]; 
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; 

    plot.barOffset = .5;
    plot.dataSource = self;


    [graph addPlot:plot];

    [plot release];
    [graph release];
    [hostingView release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want simple numeric labels, set the `labelTextStyle` and `labelFormatter` properties on the plot. If you need more complex labels, you can add the `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` method to your datasource and create your own custom labels.

See the example apps included with Core Plot for sample code. The labeling mechanism is the same for all plot types. The "Vertical Bar Chart" in the Plot Gallery app demonstrates the first technique. Several of the other plots in the Plot Gallery use the datasource technique.

Comment: Great display of knowledge and an excellent answer to help @TeamNoX resolve their question. The helpful part for me was `dataLabelForPlot`. Thanks and +1.